# How to determine data capture with a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, resampling

I am working with hourly monitoring data which consists of incomplete time series, i.e. several hours during a year (or during several years) will be absent from my dataframe.

I would like to determine the data capture, i.e. the percentage of values present in a month, a season, or a year.

This works with the following code (for demonstration written for monthly resampling) - however that piece of code appears somewhat inefficient, because I need to create a second hourly dataframe and I need to resample two dataframes.

Is there a more elegant solution to this?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# create dummy series
t1 = pd.date_range(start="1997-01-01 05:00", end="1997-04-25 17:00", freq="H")
t2 = pd.date_range(start="1997-06-11 15:00", end="1997-06-15 12:00", freq="H")
t3 = pd.date_range(start="1997-06-18 00:00", end="1997-08-22 23:00", freq="H")

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(t1)), index=t1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(t2)), index=t2)
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(t3)), index=t3)

df = pd.concat((df1, df2, df3))

# create time index with complete hourly coverage over entire years
tstart = "%i-01-01 00:00"%(df.index.year[0])
tend = "%i-12-31 23:00"%(df.index.year[-1])
tref = pd.date_range(start=tstart, end=tend, freq="H")
dfref = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros(len(tref)), index=tref)

# count number of values in reference dataframe and actual dataframe
# Example: monthly resampling
cntref = dfref.resample("MS", "count")
cnt = df.resample("MS", "count").reindex(cntref.index).fillna(0)

for i in range(len(cnt.index)):
    print cnt.index[i], cnt.values[i], cntref.values[i], cnt.values[i] / cntref.values[i]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there have been no further suggestions, it appears as if the originally posted solution is most efficient.

Answer (score 1):

`pandas`' `Timedelta` will do the trick:

```
# Time delta between rows of the df
df['index'] = df.index
pindex = df['index'].shift(1)
delta = df['index'] - pindex

# Any delta > 1H means a missing data period
missing_delta = delta[delta > pd.Timedelta('1H')]

# Sum of missing data periods divided by total period
ratio_missing = missing_delta.sum() / (df.index[-1] - df.index[0])
```

Comment: This solution is interesting and fast, but unfortunately doesn't quite do what I want, because I need the data capture of each month, not just the total fraction. But it was good to learn about Timedelta.

Answer (score 1):

You can use TimeGrouper.

```
# Create an hourly index spanning the range of your data.
idx = pd.date_range(pd.Timestamp(df.index[0].strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:00')), 
                    pd.Timestamp(df.index[-1].strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:00')), 
                    freq='H')

# Use TimeGrouper to calculate the fraction of observations from `df` that are in the 
# hourly time index.
>>> (df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('M')).size() / 
     pd.Series(idx).reindex(idx).groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('M')).size())
1997-01-31    1.000000
1997-02-28    1.000000
1997-03-31    1.000000
1997-04-30    0.825000
1997-05-31    0.000000
1997-06-30    0.563889
1997-07-31    1.000000
1997-08-31    1.000000
Freq: M, dtype: float64
```

Comment: This works (if I adapt the code to compute the idx as tref in my example above). However, on my computer it takes about twice as long as the original solution. Grouping seems to be inherently slow - its advantages may pay off if the grouping or operations are more complex.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about performance, but for a (very long) one liner you can do this once you have created 'df'... It at least has the benefits of not requiring a dummy dataframe. It should work for any period of data input and resampling.

```
month_counts = df.resample('H').mean().resample('M').count() / df.resample('H').ffill().fillna(1).resample('M').count()
```